# How do I show that text has been automatically translated

Tags: indicator

For some products on our website, we have reviews for the product on our foreign language sites.  We want to show these on the UK site (and the UK reviews on the foreign sites).  We give the ability for a review to be automatically translated (by Google Translate, then reviewed by our translators for corrections at a later date).

How do I display that the text is "translated" ?

**EDIT** We don't have specific pages for individual reviews.  To show a translated version, the user will have to at some point select "Translate Non-English reviews" (or similar wording).

We do show a flag.

Is it worthwhile recording/showing whether the translation was automatically translated or whether the translation has been added manually?

These are specifically for Product reviews.

Answer (score 2):

Add a link to the bottom of the review stating something along the lines of:

> Review translated from original [language]

This would then link back to the original review so the user could translate it for themselves if they want.

If you want it more prominent add it to the top of the review - but it could well get in the way of the content there.

Comment: As a user I would prefer a prominent way of telling me. I don't like reading some text and only then realizing that it is not a proper text but only an automatic translation (which means its quality is considerably lower!). I want to decide beforehand whether to read it, ignore it or read the original. But other users might be different...

Comment: @SebastianNegraszus - that was my thinking for putting the link at the top. I guess this comes down to what you think (or have worked out what) your target audience will be happiest with.

Answer (score 2):

You could just simply add a discrete message that says:

*This review has been translated automatically.*

with an optional '*learn more*' link.

[image]

Comment: How many of these ipsum generators do you *have*, Roger?

Comment: You just never know what's coming next :-)